# How to make the JVM crash for testing in Java?

Tags: crash, jvm

I'm looking for a web application to replicate JVM crash in my local system.

I would like to test this scenario in JBoss EAP and Weblogic Server.

Comment: Looks like I found the answer in this site, Click [link](http://www.wikiconsole.com/askme/questions/how-to-make-the-jvm-crash-for-testing-in-java/)

Comment: Do you want to crash out the JVM or just throw an Exception or Error?  These are very different.

Answer (score 0):

maybe just go to the [JVM bugs database](http://bugs.java.com) and search for "crash".